# HTML input validation (Angular) dependent on other fields

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two fields which both take numbers. One must always be higher than the other. For example you can have a field for `age`, and then a field for `older sibling age` which of course must be greater depending on the first field.

My fields are like this:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="age" required> 

<input type="number" ng-model="olderSiblingAge" required>
```

I've tried using `min="age"` in the `olderSibling` input, but no luck, can still go below it.

Comment: try `min="{{age}}"`

Comment: min on input allows irrespective of specified min value but it will allow only legal values to submit - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to interpolate the value like this: `min="{{vm.age}}"` as specified in the [number input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) documentation regarding to AngularJS.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.age = 1;
    vm.olderSiblingAge = 2;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <label> Age </label> <br />
  <input type="number" ng-model="vm.age" required ng-change="vm.olderSiblingAge = vm.age">

  <br /><br />

  <label> Older sibling age </label> <br />
  <input type="number" ng-model="vm.olderSiblingAge" required min="{{vm.age}}">
</div>
```

Note: I've used the *controller-as* syntax. Of course you can use it as your were doing it with the `$scope` notation like this `min="{{age}}"`

Answer (score 0):

TRY USING THIS CODE

```
<input type="number" ng-model="age" required> 

<input type="number" ng-change="olderSiblingAge = (olderSiblingAge < age)?age+1:olderSiblingAge" ng-model="olderSiblingAge" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using ng-blur to compare entered values

code sample https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XEJpYa?editors=1010

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
Age <input type="number" ng-model="age" required> 
Sibling Age <input type="number" ng-model="olderSiblingAge" required ng-blur="check()">{{olderSiblingAge}}

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('test',[]);

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.check = function(){
      if($scope.age  > $scope.olderSiblingAge){
         $scope.olderSiblingAge = null
        alert("older sibling age should be greater than age")
      }
    }
})
```